# Keeping niddus a secret

Tags: minhag, niddah

Is the general custom of Jewish women to not reveal to others when they are a niddah and when they go to the mikveh, a custom that developed in America or is it an older custom than that? It seems from the Talmud that in those days women wore different clothes when they were in niddus so it would have been a difficult thing to hide. When did this attitude of hiding niddus/mikveh begin?

Comment: It's not just Jewish women. I've in fact never met a gentile woman who has told me she was menstruating.

Comment: Adding to @DoubleAA's cooment, the custom most certainly did not develop in America. Not that I specifically asked, but, inevitably, my grandmother taught me a bit abouit the "birds and the bees" and if my memory is correct (as I age, it gets a bit foggy, y'know :-) she explained that no Jewish woman that she knew in Poland, Holland or Belgium told anyone except their husband when they were menstruating.

Comment: This is a minhag how? Why is it any one else's business? This is a rather private matter. Normal people don't discuss this is public.