# Putting a ring on a Kallah that's a niddah

Tags: halacha, wedding, niddah, jewelry

During a regular chupah the choson puts the ring on the kallah's finger. What happens in a case of when the kallah is a niddah by the chupah being that the choson can't touch the kallah? Who puts the ring on?

Comment: Remember to forward practical questions to a rabbi.

Comment: Ignoring other issues of chuppat nidda, he could drop the ring into her hand.

Comment: @mevaqesh it says in a couple of places that the choson puts the ring specifically on the index finger so it seems he should specifically put it on her vs just giving it to her

Comment: That's a nice custom. But not every nice custom  is worth risking an actual prohibition over. Halakhicaly he need not give a ring at all, asks can give any good (Or service) of monetary value. Furthermore, he need not do so in person but can do so via an agent. She need not receive it in person either, but can similarly appoint a messenger in her stead. There are many halakhically appropriate variations on the giving process that would avoid nidda issues.

Comment: If you think some post of the procedure is mandatory, you should edit that into the question. You should also clarify whether you are asking what different people do practically, or what student halakhically acceptable solutions are.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68290/501

Comment: Related: Last paragraph of [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48970/13438).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the question about [Menstruating on Wedding Day](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68290/501) there seem to be various customs.

- The groom is careful not to touch the bride when putting the ring on her finger.

  - This seems to be the common custom, and is the one mentioned in all halacha books I've seen. E.g. [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=v3tpiZ-uxuAC&lpg=PA154&ots=JtM0gndr0m&dq=chupas%20niddah%20ring&pg=PA154#v=onepage&q=chupas%20niddah%20ring&f=false).
- Some communities would just pass the ring in such a situation.

  - This was mentioned but not elaborated on.
- A commentator above mentioned that he could drop the ring into her hand